# How to implement dendency module linking in my module

Tags: react-native, npm, dependencies, package, asyncstorage

Im currently working on my own package module for React Native.
As dependency it will have react-native-community/async-storage.

Async-storage for installation requires:

- Linking
- Cocoa pods install

So the question is how can i add this dependency in my module in that way so end will only need to:

- npm install 'MyModuleName'

And thats it, without any additional linking and installations.
Since the async-storage dependency will be handled in 'MyModuleName'/node_modules folder, and not in the project one.

Answer (score 0):

No you can’t do this you have to use async-storage as a `peerDependencies` that’s the only way to use other libs in your module.

Comment: But i checked other modules who use async-storage and in package.json file async-storage is defined as `dependencies`, not `peerDependencies`

Comment: Could you please tell me an example module

Comment: To use above module asyncstorage must be in your project